# map() does not return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a button onClick I have a function that makes a GET petition and recieves a json array. When I try showing that to the user, nothing changes, although if I put a console.log inside the map I does show and iterate though all the objects.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/GetApunte',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {            
            this.datosCargados=true;
            this.anotaciones=responseJson;
            //cuerpo()
            
                return(
                    <tbody>
                        {this.anotaciones.map((anotacion, index)=>{
                            const {titulo, body} = anotacion
                            return(
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{titulo}</td>
                                    <td>{body}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })}
                    </tbody> 
                );
        });
```

The structure of my class is like this:

```
export default class Apuntes extends React.Component{
state ={}
getApuntes(){}

render(){
    return(
        <button onClick={()=> this.getApuntes()}>Mostrar Apuntes</button>
    )
}
}
```

The anotaciones is inside the state, thats why I use this.anotaciones

Comment: Generally, you want to set state when the data comes in. So even if you somewhere `return fetch...` all that you show here, you would still only have a `Promise` of JSX that you would need to `await` or `.then`.

Comment: Returning a JSX `<tbody>` from your async function isn't going to add it to the document. What you should be doing is updating _state_ with the remote data and rendering that state in your rendered HTML

Comment: You're returning a JSX from the fetch and you're not using the result in any way.

Comment: This line `this.anotaciones=responseJson;` is illegal, you're not allowed to directly mutate state. Additionally, as zhulien points out you *aren't rendering the result of your fetch*.

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply return data from a promise directly into React component as it would not be easy to control dataflow state between an async function and a synchronous component.
Try following this pratice:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]) // array empty on init
async fetch() {
    return fetchedArray; // get array from remote 
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchdArray().then(fetchedArr => setArr(fetchedArr);
}, []); // this is equal to componentDidMount in class component

return (<div>{arr.map(...)}</div>)
```

By this way the `arr` is always updated its state to the screen, from empty until populated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the JSX in the promise, just save anotaciones into a the state. You can extract the generation of the table into a separate function, like

```
const generarAnotaciones = () =>
    <tbody>
        {this.anotaciones.map((anotacion, index) => {
            const { titulo, body } = anotacion
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{titulo}</td>
                    <td>{body}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })}
    </tbody>
```

Then your class should be something like this:

```
export default class Apuntes extends React.Component {
    state = {}
    getApuntes() { }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={() => this.getApuntes()}>Mostrar Apuntes</button>
                {generarAnotaciones()}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```